# How to scrape span content using urllib2?

Tags: python, urllib2

I want to **scrape** all *.wordpress urls mentioned in a social bookmarking website. The urls in pages are in this format:

```
<span class="domain">somedomain.com </span>
```

Here is what I came up with:

```
import os
import urllib2
import re
from os.path import basename
from urlparse import urlsplit
import time


baseurl = 'https://targetwebsite/pages/'

print baseurl


spage = int(raw_input("Start page?"))
epage = int(raw_input("End page?"))

for p in range (spage, epage):
    url= baseurl+ str(p)
    print url
    urlContent = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    #WHAT REGEXP HERE?
    domainUrls = re.findall('span .*.wordpress.com (.*?) ', urlContent)

    try:

    for dUrl in domainUrls:
        print dUrl
 
    except:
    print "an error occured"
    pass
```

I tried different regexps but none worked. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please explain what you mean by "not working". Please include **full** tracebacks (if they exist).

Comment: Use an HTML Parser, like BeautifulSoup.

Comment: @Veedrac. Thanks mate. I am new to Python and don't have any tracebacks. Just nothing displays with print statement.

Comment: @ComputerFellow would you mind explaining how?

Comment: @starluv I suggest you look up a Regex that matches HTML and just copy that. There are bound to be hundreds.

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ not scarp or scrap

Answer (score 0):

A loose answer is just

```
([^ ]*\.)?wordpress.com(\/[^ ]*)?
```